# Is the return value "-1" of the function socket close() method possible?

Tags: networking, socket

Under which circumstances is it possible to produce a return value of -1 when closing a network socket using it's close(int fildesc) method? I suppose it is possible with an invalid fildesc number, but can it happen with a valid, existing socket?

How should a program react in case of this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html) describes some possible situations where `close()` returns -1 on valid file descriptors:

> Not checking the return value of close() is a common but nevertheless
>   serious programming error.  It is quite possible that errors on a
>   previous write(2) operation are first reported at the final close().
>   Not checking the return value when closing the file may lead to
>   silent loss of data.  This can especially be observed with NFS and
>   with disk quota.

I suppose this part would apply to other kernels than Linux.  Then it's followed by this caveat (emphasized by me):

> **Note that the return value should be used only for
>   diagnostics.**  In particular close() should not be retried after an
>   EINTR since this may cause a reused descriptor from another thread to
>   be closed.

You might want to read some rationale for this found in [this lwn.net article](http://lwn.net/Articles/576478/):

> The file descriptor passed to close() is de-allocated early in the processing of the system call and the same descriptor could already have been handed out to another thread by the time close() returns.

So, for socket descriptors we might encounter `EINTR` on closing a socket especially after sending bulk of data with it, however we should *never* write code like this on Linux:

```
while (close(sock) == -1 && errno == EINTR);
```

Comment: The statement should follow the man page, thus it should be `while (close(sock) == -1 ...` and not compare to `< 0`.

Comment: @ott-- Well, fixed.  Actually we should not do such a retry loop...

Comment: If the code I write is explicitly single-threaded, are there "background" threads (for lack of a better word) that execute without my code starting them? That is, in a program that never calls pthread_create(), should I think about the EINTR situation with respect to closing a file descriptor?